# Is projective geometry important for general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Today someone claimed that projective geometry is one of the building blocks for general relativity. I really do not know much about projective geometry and I only had one lecture about GR, so I fail to see a connection between the two subjects. Sure, differential geometry is important, but is there a connection to projective geometry?

To which extend and in which sense is the above statement correct?

Comment: Related on [hsm.se]: [How did Einstein get inspired by projective geometry?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7169/65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importance is in the eye of the beholder, but e.g. Penrose famously reformulated [SR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity) using projective [twistor space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twistor_space) $P_3(\mathbb{C})$. This can be generalized to [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity). Perhaps OP's someone is referring to this?

Projective geometry also appears in many modern physics theories, such as, e.g., twistor formulation of [${\cal N}=4$ SYM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_%3D_4_supersymmetric_Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory), or Calabi-Yau compactifications in [ST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory), etc.

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource on the generalisation of Penrose's approach to GR?

Comment: My "someone" has no real background in GR or physics but is more like a layman who just learned about projective geometry. I assume that he has just heard in a lecture that there is a connection between GR and projective geometry and this triggered the statement.

Comment: Seconding the request for sources for the generalization to GR.

Answer (score 1):

Light cones are projective spaces. The null rays satisfy the condition of being a set of rays modulo scale. This is because then have no length! Light cones then form a projective Lorentz group, sometimes denoted by $PSL(2,~\mathbb Z)$. In general relativity sets of null rays form similar structures, where an event horizon is a congruence of null rays.

Comment: Take a light cone in 2d Minkowski space. It's just the crossing of two straight lines. How is that a projective space? What does *"Light cones then form a projective Lorentz group"* mean - what is the group operation on "light cones"?

Comment: See Ward and Wells "Twistor Geometry and Field Theory" pages 50-52. That light cones are projective rays is discussed in a number of sources.

Comment: The relevant pages in my edition of Ward & Wells do not talk about projective spaces at all, they talk about conformal equivalences and conformal compactification, and a conformal space is something entirely different from a projective space. Also, please specify how "light cones" can form a group, let alone a "projective Lorentz group", given that there is no obvious group operation on them.

Comment: Strange. my edition not only talks about light cones there are picture of them and on 52 the connection to projective geometry.

Comment: @ACuriousMind so can I say that light cones are projective spaces?