# Is there a book about projective geometry in physics?

Tags: resource-recommendations, geometry, mathematics

From [Complex projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space):

> In quantum physics, the wave function associated to a pure state of a quantum mechanical system is a probability amplitude, meaning that it has unit norm, and has an inessential overall phase: that is, the wave function of a pure state is naturally a point in the projective Hilbert space of the state space.

Or from [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere#Applications)

> The Riemann sphere has many uses in physics. In quantum mechanics, points on the complex projective line are natural values for photon polarization states, spin states of massive particles of spin 1/2, and 2-state particles in general (see also Quantum bit and Bloch sphere). The Riemann sphere has been suggested as a relativistic model for the celestial sphere.[2] In string theory, the worldsheets of strings are Riemann surfaces, and the Riemann sphere, being the simplest Riemann surface, plays a significant role. It is also important in twistor theory.

In general, is there a book or paper exploits the application of projective geometry in physics systematically? I'd like to see not only in quantum mechanics or relativity, but also in classical mechanics as well.

Comment: E.g. look up works by Penrose, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338244/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: You can have a look at G. Naber, "Topology, geometry, and gauge fields -Foundations", Springer, 2011

Comment: Projective geometry is very important in String Theory, as compact Calabi-Yau manifolds are projective via the Kodaira embedding theorem